# How to get an objects data inside a function and pass it to a different function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have this middleware i'm trying to create for my app and i'm wondering on how to get the object's data, inside a separate function, so i can use it on a different function. Thanks in advance.

```
module.exports = {
    myfunction: function(req, res, next) {
        ...
        body:{
            id:
        }
        ...
    },

    process: function(req, res, next) {
        const id = myfunction.body.id;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
    ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do. But in order to be able to call `myfunction` from `process`, you need to declare it outside of the module.exports. For example:

```
const myfunction = (req, res, next) => {
  return {
    body: {
      id: "id"
    }
  };
};

module.exports = {
  myfunction,
  process: function(req, res, next) {
    const id = myfunction(req, res, next).body.id;
  }
};
```

Comment: what if i'm also trying to export myfunction and process at the same time for some other use?

Comment: I think this might work but i missed something for myfunction it's actually ```var options={body:{data:{id:}}} request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
    return next();
  });

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with those functions and then export that object. The pattern I normally use is:

```
const self = {
  myfunction: function (req, res, next) {
    let body = {
      id: 1,
    };
    return body
  },

  process: function (req, res, next) {
    const id = self.myfunction().id;
  },
};

module.exports = self;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
module.exports = {
myfunction: function(req, res, next) {
    return {
        body: {
            id: 
        }
    }
},

process: function(req, res, next) {
    const id = this.myfunction().body.id;
}
}
```

Comment: "TypeError: this.myfunction is not a function" this is the error it shows

Comment: If you are not 100% sure about the answer its better to test your code and then give an answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)